# Reindent html with xmllint

Tags: indentation, external-command

I'm trying to reindent current HTML file with this command from inside vim :

```
:!xmllint --html --format % 2>/dev/null
```

But, all it does it displays the output to stdout without actually modifying the file.

EDIT0 : I just found this but I'm not sure if this the correct way to do this :

```
:%!xmllint --html --format - 2>/dev/null
```

`:%` stands for the vim range `:1,$` (the entire file) and `-` tells `xmllint` to read data from `stdin`

EDIT1 : @statox, Finally, I'll be using `equalprg` :

```
autocmd FileType html let &l:equalprg='xmllint --html --format --recover - 2>/dev/null' "Pretty print HTML when 'gg=G' is pressed
```

Here's some vim help about the `let &` syntax:

> ```
> :h let-&
> :let &{option-name} = {expr1}                   :let-option :let-&
>                         Set option {option-name} to the result of the
>                         expression {expr1}.  A String or Number value is
>                         always converted to the type of the option.
>                         For an option local to a window or buffer the effect
>                         is just like using the :set command: both the local
>                         value and the global value are changed.
>                         Example:
>                                 :let &path = &path . ',/usr/local/include'
>                         This also works for terminal codes in the form t_xx.
>                         But only for alphanumerical names.  Example:
>                                 :let &t_k1 = "\<Esc>[234;"
>                         When the code does not exist yet it will be created as
>                         a terminal key code, there is no error.
>
> ...
> :let &l:{option-name} = {expr1}
> :let &l:{option-name} .= {expr1}
> :let &l:{option-name} += {expr1}
> :let &l:{option-name} -= {expr1}
>                         Like above, but only set the local value of an option
>                         (if there is one).  Works like :setlocal.
>
> :let &g:{option-name} = {expr1}
> :let &g:{option-name} .= {expr1}
> :let &g:{option-name} += {expr1}
> :let &g:{option-name} -= {expr1}
>                         Like above, but only set the global value of an option
>                         (if there is one).  Works like :setglobal.
> ```

Comment: What you have in your edit is what I would do, so I would say it's correct.

Comment: I think I'd rather use [`:h 'equalprg'`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27equalprg%27) but you can check the different answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21408222/4194289) which should give you the information you need.

Comment: @statox Thanks for your solution. I've added it in my EDIT1 by replacing `setlocal equalprg` by `let &l:equalprg`

Comment: @SebMa It would be great if you posted your solution as an answer rather than as an edit of your question (and you should mark this answer as accepted): This way future readers will easily know that you got a working solution.

Comment: @statox YOU did the solving here. Why not create your answer so that I can award and accept it and then I'll move my EDIT1 from my question inside your new answer ?